# How to set table cell checkmark based on a user default setting

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple table that has 2 cells as checkmark options (these are meant to be settings options):

1. Setting 1
2. Setting 2

In the Storyboard I have the prototype cells' accessory set to checkmark. This of course automatically checks both of the cells when they're built.

What I can't figure out how to do is check the user default settings upon `viewDidLoad` and then determine which of the cells should be checked. These particular settings will be set in the `NSUserDefaults` as `Setting 1 = true` and `Setting 2 = false`. This will be the out of box settings.

I know it's got to do with an if statement of some sort. Maybe something like this:

```
if settingsCell[0] && settingDay == true{
    settingsCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
}
```

But I can't figure out:

> a) what the proper syntax is 
>  b) where it should be placed in the
>   UIViewController (viewDidLoad as stated earlier or in some tableView
>   function) so it will checkmark the cells based on the actual settings?

Any help would be very much appreciated!